# How to solve TypeError at /api/register/ Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use groups.set() instead

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

```
class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        # fields = '__all__'

        fields = ('id', 'username', 'email', 'password', 'is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser'
                  , 'Designation', 'Address', 'groups', 'profile')

    def create(self, validated_data, ):
        user = Person.objects.create(
            username=validated_data['username'],
            email=validated_data['email'],
            password=validated_data['password'],
            Designation=validated_data['Designation'],
            is_active=validated_data['is_active'],
            is_staff=validated_data['is_staff'],
            is_superuser=validated_data['is_superuser'],
            Address=validated_data['Address'],
            profile=validated_data['profile'],
            groups=validated_data['groups']

        )

        user.set_password(make_password(validated_data['password']))
        user.save()
        return user
```

How can I solve the following error:

```
TypeError at /api/register/ Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use groups.set() instead
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not populate `groups` when you create a `Person`, since at that moment the `Person` has no primary key yet, and thus that primary key can not be used for the junction table of the many-to-many relation.

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    user = Person.objects.create(
        username=validated_data['username'],
        email=validated_data['email'],
        password=validated_data['password'],
        Designation=validated_data['Designation'],
        is_active=validated_data['is_active'],
        is_staff=validated_data['is_staff'],
        is_superuser=validated_data['is_superuser'],
        Address=validated_data['Address'],
        profile=validated_data['profile'],
        # no groups=…
    )
    # add groups to the user ↓
    user.groups.add(*validated_data['groups'])
    user.set_password(make_password(validated_data['password']))
    user.save()
    return user
```

the logic can be shortened with:

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    groups = validated_data.pop('groups', ())
    user = Person.objects.create(
        **validated_data
    )
    # add groups to the user ↓
    user.groups.add(*groups)
    user.set_password(make_password(validated_data['password']))
    user.save()
    return user
```

Comment: sir i using user model with proxy

Comment: sir successfully create or post